# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in the line

Tags: php, html, syntax-error

```
<?php


$tombol=$_POST['request'];
$no=$_POST['number'];
$otp=$_POST['otp'];

$secret = '83415d06-ec4e-11e6-a41b-6c40088ab51e';
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'X-AppVersion: 3.27.0';
$headers[] = "X-Uniqueid: ac94e5d0e7f3f".rand(111,999);
$headers[] = 'X-Location: -6.405821,106.064193';

if(isset($tombol))
    {
      if($tombol =='Get OTP')
          {

        $numbers = $number[0].$number[1];
        $numberx = $number[5];
        if($numbers == "08") { 
            $number = str_replace("08","628",$number);
        } elseif ($numberx == " ") {
            $number = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "",$number);
            $number = "1".$number;
        }
        $nama = nama();
        $email = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "", $nama) . mt_rand(100,999) . "@gmail.com");
        $data1 = '{"name":"' . $nama . '","email":"' . $email . '","phone":"+' . $number . '","signed_up_country":"ID"}';
        $reg = curl('https://api.gojekapi.com/v5/customers', $data1, $headers);
        $regs = json_decode($reg[0]);

        if($regs->success == true) {
           echo "OTP Berhasil Terkirim";


      }
         else if($tombol =='Execute'){


            $data2 = '{"client_name":"gojek:cons:android","data":{"otp":"' . $otp . '","otp_token":"' . $regs->data->otp_token . '"},"client_secret":"' . $secret . '"}';
            $verif = curl('https://api.gojekapi.com/v5/customers/phone/verify', $data2, $headers);
            $verifs = json_decode($verif[0]);
            if($verifs->success == true) {
                echo "Berhasil Login Ke gojek\n";
                echo "Tunggu 5 Detik..";
                sleep(2);
                echo "Redeem VOC in";
                echo "3";
                echo "2";
                echo "1";
                sleep(1);
                // Claim Voucher
                $token = $verifs->data->access_token;
                $headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer '.$token;
    echo "(TOKENmu => .$token. | NOMOR => .$number. )";  
    echo "[+]Process Redeem GOFOODBOBA07 \n";
                sleep(5);
                $data3 = '{"promo_code":"GOFOODBOBA07"}';
                $claim = curl('https://api.gojekapi.com/go-promotions/v1/promotions/enrollments', $data3, $headers);
                $claims = json_decode($claim[0]);
                    echo $claims->data->message;
                    echo "\n";
                    echo "Tunggu 15 Detik!\n";
                    sleep(15);
                    echo "[+]Process Redeem COBAINGOJEK \n";
                $data4 = '{"promo_code":"COBAINGOJEK"}';
                $claim1 = curl('https://api.gojekapi.com/go-promotions/v1/promotions/enrollments', $data4, $headers);
                $claims1 = json_decode($claim1[0]);
                    echo $claims1->data->message;
                    echo "\n";
                    echo "Tunggu 15 Detik!\n";
                    sleep(15);
                    echo "[+]Process Redeem AYOCOBAGOJEK \n";
                $data5 = '{"promo_code":"AYOCOBAGOJEKGOJEK"}';
                $claim2 = curl('https://api.gojekapi.com/go-promotions/v1/promotions/enrollments', $data5, $headers);
                $claims2 = json_decode($claim2[0]);
                    echo $claims2->data->message;
                    }
                    }
    function nama()
 {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://ninjaname.horseridersupply.com/indonesian_name.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $ex = curl_exec($ch);
    // $rand = json_decode($rnd_get, true);
    preg_match_all('~(&bull; (.*?)<br/>&bull; )~', $ex, $name);
    return $name[2][mt_rand(0, 14) ];
    }

function curl($url, $fields = null, $headers = null)    
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        if ($fields !== null) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
        }
        if ($headers !== null) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        }
        $result   = curl_exec($ch);
        $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);

        return array(
            $result,
            $httpcode
        );
    }


//proses
    $filecounter=("counter.txt");
$kunjungan=file($filecounter);
$kunjungan[0]++;
$file=fopen($filecounter,"w");
fputs($file,"$kunjungan[0]");
fclose($file);
?>
<?php } ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">


        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Hi!</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/custom.css">
        <!-- Favicon and touch icons -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/ico/favicon.png">

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container ">
            <div class="row">            
                <div class="login-container col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                     <div class="login-title text-center">
                            <h2><span>Kuota<strong> Tsel</strong></span></h2>
                     </div>
                    <div class="login-content">
                        <div class="login-header ">
                            <h3><strong>Welcome,</strong></h3>
                            <h5>Nikmati Selagi bisa dinikmati</h5>
                        </div>
                       <form action="" method="post" class="login-form">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <div class="pos-r">                                        
                         <div class="form-group">
                         <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                    <input type="text" class="form-username form-control" name="number" placeholder="Input Number 62xx"value="<?php if(isset($_POST["request"])){echo $no;};?>"required>

                  </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <input type="submit"name="request" class="btn btn-primary form-control"value="Get OTP">
                        </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                     <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                    <input type="text" class="form-username form-control"name="otp" placeholder="Input OTP"autocomplete="off">

                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="submit"name="request" class="btn btn-primary form-control"value="Execute">
                  </div>

                         </form>
                         <div class="text-center">
                    <small>
                         Viewers: <?=
                        $kunjungan[0];
                         ?>
                    </small>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="text-center">
                    <?php if(isset($_POST["request"])){
                   echo "<div class='alert alert-primary' role='alert'>"
                           .$msg.
                        "</div>";};?>                            

                        </div> <!-- end  login-body -->                     
                    </div><!-- end  login-content -->  
                    <div class="login-footer text-center template">
                         <h5>Script Created By <a href="https://www.github.com/rap07" class="bold"> RanggaAp</a></h5>                   
                    </div>
                </div>  <!-- end  login-container -->      

            </div>
        </div><!-- end container -->

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: you have made many mistakes when place quotes double(`"`) and single(`'`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of errors are there in you code.

I have gone through the code and i have done modification. Please try the below code

```
<?php

$tombol = $_POST['request'];
$no = $_POST['number'];
$otp = $_POST['otp'];

$secret = '83415d06-ec4e-11e6-a41b-6c40088ab51e';
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'X-AppVersion: 3.27.0';
$headers[] = "X-Uniqueid: ac94e5d0e7f3f" . rand(111, 999);
$headers[] = 'X-Location: -6.405821,106.064193';

if (isset($tombol))
{
    if ($tombol == 'Get OTP')
    {

        $numbers = $number[0] . $number[1];
        $numberx = $number[5];
        if ($numbers == "08")
        {
            $number = str_replace("08", "628", $number);
        }
        elseif ($numberx == " ")
        {
            $number = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $number);
            $number = "1" . $number;
        }
        $nama = nama();
        $email = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "", $nama) . mt_rand(100, 999) . "@gmail.com");
        $data1 = '{"name":"' . $nama . '","email":"' . $email . '","phone":"+' . $number . '","signed_up_country":"ID"}';
        $reg = curl('https://api.gojekapi.com/v5/customers', $data1, $headers);
        $regs = json_decode($reg[0]);

        if ($regs->success == true)
        {
            echo "OTP Berhasil Terkirim";

        }
        else if ($tombol == 'Execute')
        {

            $data2 = '{"client_name":"gojek:cons:android","data":{"otp":"' . $otp . '","otp_token":"' . $regs
                ->data->otp_token . '"},"client_secret":"' . $secret . '"}';
            $verif = curl('https://api.gojekapi.com/v5/customers/phone/verify', $data2, $headers);
            $verifs = json_decode($verif[0]);
            if ($verifs->success == true)
            {
                echo "Berhasil Login Ke gojek\n";
                echo "Tunggu 5 Detik..";
                sleep(2);
                echo "Redeem VOC in";
                echo "3";
                echo "2";
                echo "1";
                sleep(1);
                // Claim Voucher
                $token = $verifs
                    ->data->access_token;
                $headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token;
                echo "(TOKENmu => .$token. | NOMOR => .$number. )";
                echo "[+]Process Redeem GOFOODBOBA07 \n";
                sleep(5);
                $data3 = '{"promo_code":"GOFOODBOBA07"}';
                $claim = curl('https://api.gojekapi.com/go-promotions/v1/promotions/enrollments', $data3, $headers);
                $claims = json_decode($claim[0]);
                echo $claims
                    ->data->message;
                echo "\n";
                echo "Tunggu 15 Detik!\n";
                sleep(15);
                echo "[+]Process Redeem COBAINGOJEK \n";
                $data4 = '{"promo_code":"COBAINGOJEK"}';
                $claim1 = curl('https://api.gojekapi.com/go-promotions/v1/promotions/enrollments', $data4, $headers);
                $claims1 = json_decode($claim1[0]);
                echo $claims1
                    ->data->message;
                echo "\n";
                echo "Tunggu 15 Detik!\n";
                sleep(15);
                echo "[+]Process Redeem AYOCOBAGOJEK \n";
                $data5 = '{"promo_code":"AYOCOBAGOJEKGOJEK"}';
                $claim2 = curl('https://api.gojekapi.com/go-promotions/v1/promotions/enrollments', $data5, $headers);
                $claims2 = json_decode($claim2[0]);
                echo $claims2
                    ->data->message;
            }
        }
        function nama()
        {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://ninjaname.horseridersupply.com/indonesian_name.php");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            $ex = curl_exec($ch);
            // $rand = json_decode($rnd_get, true);
            preg_match_all('~(&bull; (.*?)<br/>&bull; )~', $ex, $name);
            return $name[2][mt_rand(0, 14) ];
        }

        function curl($url, $fields = null, $headers = null)
        {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            if ($fields !== null)
            {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
            }
            if ($headers !== null)
            {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            }
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            curl_close($ch);

            return array(
                $result,
                $httpcode
            );
        }

        //proses
        $filecounter = ("counter.txt");
        $kunjungan = file($filecounter);
        $kunjungan[0]++;
        $file = fopen($filecounter, "w");
        fputs($file, $kunjungan[0]);
        fclose($file);
      }
  }
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">


        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Hi!</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/custom.css">
        <!-- Favicon and touch icons -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/ico/favicon.png">

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container ">
            <div class="row">            
                <div class="login-container col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                     <div class="login-title text-center">
                            <h2><span>Kuota<strong> Tsel</strong></span></h2>
                     </div>
                    <div class="login-content">
                        <div class="login-header ">
                            <h3><strong>Welcome,</strong></h3>
                            <h5>Nikmati Selagi bisa dinikmati</h5>
                        </div>
                       <form action="" method="post" class="login-form">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <div class="pos-r">                                        
                         <div class="form-group">
                         <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                    <input type="text" class="form-username form-control" name="number" placeholder="Input Number 62xx"value="<?php if (isset($_POST["request"]))
        {
            echo $no;
        }; ?>"required>

                  </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <input type="submit"name="request" class="btn btn-primary form-control"value="Get OTP">
                        </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                     <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                    <input type="text" class="form-username form-control"name="otp" placeholder="Input OTP"autocomplete="off">

                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="submit"name="request" class="btn btn-primary form-control"value="Execute">
                  </div>

                         </form>
                         <div class="text-center">
                    <small>
                         Viewers: <?php
        echo $kunjungan[0];
?>
                    </small>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="text-center">
                    <?php if (isset($_POST["request"]))
        { ?>
                   <div class='alert alert-primary' role='alert'><?php echo $msg; ?></div>
                   <?php
        } ?>                            

                        </div> <!-- end  login-body -->                     
                    </div><!-- end  login-content -->  
                    <div class="login-footer text-center template">
                         <h5>Script Created By <a href="https://www.github.com/rap07" class="bold"> RanggaAp</a></h5>                   
                    </div>
                </div>  <!-- end  login-container -->      

            </div>
        </div><!-- end container -->

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: There's was, i accidentally delete ' code, but the error is in end of file

Comment: Please see the full code and help me

Comment: What errors are you getting after updating my code ?

Comment: Syntax error, Unexpected end of file in the line

Comment: In which line number ?

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file on line 212

Comment: Now you check it once . I have updated full code

Comment: where should I check it?

Comment: You were missing two closing flower brackets. I have added that and run the above code in your server .

Comment: If it's working accept my anwwer

Comment: It's working, and i've already accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

Also, modify this line,

```
    $claim = curl(1/promotienrollments', $data3, $headers);
```

To

```
    $claim = curl('1/promotienrollments', $data3, $headers);
```